# iTunes Connect submitting error

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect

"Unable to process application info.plist validation"
Get this error second day in a row. Google said that this error caused by apple problems, but I'm not sure. There no any references about the same problem for last month. So I think, that it can be caused by something else. Any suggestions?

P.S. When I try to submit app with App Loader, get this:
"The bundle at path is not signed using an Apple submission sertificate."

---

Solution >>>

I recreated project with new simple name (without symbols). Then I added all new files to the project and copied code into already existing files (ViewController, Delegate, Icon and Launch Assets Catalog). And the last - I changed Bundle identifier and Bundle display name in info.plist file.

Comment: Did you sign the application with an App Store distribution provisioning profile?

Comment: Have you tried validating your code to see if that works?  Code validation performs a check against iTunes connect to see if you have a valid app/bundle waiting for upload.

Comment: How exactly should I sign the app? I created provisioning profile and chose this profile in App Loader.
Validation is dont work, get "unable to process application info.plist validation" error.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your app identifier in your info.plist file is not readable somehow ("unable to process application info.plist validation") and then it fails to submit because your distribution profile does not match with that app identifier ("The bundle at path is not signed using an Apple submitting certificate.").

EDIT:

I have ${PRODUCT_NAME} on my bundle name and my bundle display name. I would expect you not to have any problems as your app has no spaces in its name but you could try to reset this to the default (${PRODUCT_NAME}) and see where does that take you.

Also, I don't remember but I'm using the bundle version as a number, not a version identifier. Try to set it as "1" and check.

Apart from that everything looks normal.

Comment: So what can I do to check it? I tried to recreate project but anyway got same messages.

Comment: Check your info.plist file in the supporting files group or in the info tab of the project. The field is "Bundle name". Provide with more data so we can help.

Comment: Added screenshots to the first post.